# Пожалуйста объясните пунктуацию: почему не выделяется запятыми "в порыве к счастью"?

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь, вводные-слова

*"Алые паруса" - поэма, утверждающая силу человеческого духа, просвеченная насквозь, как утренним солнцем, любовью к жизни, к душевной юности и верой в то, что человек в порыве к счастью способен своими руками совершать чудеса.*

Comment: Галина, а зачем Вы трогали шапку? Насколько я вижу, у автора было два вопроса, которые Вы объединили в один, ссылающийся только на момент с "в порыве к счастью".

Answer (score 1):

Разбираю по порядку:

1.**Поэма, утверждающая силу человеческого духа**.
Запятая необходима на основании ПО, стоящего **после определяемого слова**. Яркий пример обособленного определения.

**Поэма, просвеченная насквозь, как утренним солнцем, любовью к жизни, к душевной юности и верой в то, что человек в порыве к счастью способен своими руками совершать чудеса**.

Здесь, опять же, ПО после определяемого слова. Если хотите, запятая также может ставиться на основании перечисления однородных ПО, что является более правильным объяснением, как я считаю. Запятые, ограничивающие "как утренним солнцем", необходимы на правах сравнительного оборота. Сравнение приводится к слову "насквозь". Запятая перед "к душевной юности" обусловлена однородными несогласованными  определениями, относящимися к слову "любовь". Запятая перед "что" объясняется вводом придаточного предложения.

2.Запятыми оборот "в порыве к счастью" не обособляется потому, что автор хотел подчеркнуть, что человек, способный совершить чудеса, должен обладать именно этим признаком. Но отделение данной конструкции занятыми также возможно. Тогда смысл будет противоположным.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Пожалуйста объясните пунктуацию

Слишком общий вопрос.

> 2. Почему: почему не выделяется запятыми "в порыве к счастью"?

Автор не вкладывает тот смысл, который требовал бы обособления. Здесь, судя по всему, оборот совмещает функции обстоятельства условия ("когда?", "при каком условии?") и/или причины (почему?). И в том и другом случае обособление подобных оборотов возможно лишь как авторская пунктуация, подчеркивающая вторичность этого условия или наполняющая оборот смыслом оговорки. Мне даже трудно подобрать пример, где такое обособление было бы обязательным...
Ну вот, например, такое можно рассмотреть.

***... и верой в то, что человек, при некоторых условиях, способен своими
руками совершать чудеса.***

Смысл другой. В нашем примере явно не о том речь.
"В порыве к счастью" - ключевой момент всей фразы, обособление противоречило бы смыслу, вкладываемому автором.

Единственное, что могу добавить, обособление тут - это не чисто пунктуационная ошибка, отчасти это и ошибка понимания текста. Такое у студентов РКИ часто встречается, когда они в погоне за формальными правилами теряют понимание смысла.